# ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider and authentication using userDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, active-directory, ldap

I have two different users in my application. Ldap users and api users. Ldap users have privilege to access an endpoint and api users a different endpoint. I have implemented the api user authentication using UserDetailsService and having the details in my application.yaml file.
The issue I am facing now is, The endpoint that only Ldap users should access is now being accessed my api users as well. How can I prevent this. Please find my code snippet below

```
public class ServiceSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ldapProvider")
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

// security for apiuser
              http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(“/abcd/**).hasRole(“admin”)
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and().userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
      

// security for ldap users
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(“/ghhgh” + "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .exceptionHandling();
    }

    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails user = User.withUsername(“api”)
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(“test”))
                .roles(“admin”)
              return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: From your code I cannot tell which endpoint is created for which group of users, but if you want to seperate them, give the api users a role `api` and the ldap user a role `ldap` and then secure your endpoints with these roles `.antMatchers("ldap_endpoint").hasRole("ldap")` `.antMatchers("api_endpoint").hasRole("api")`

Comment: @AmI have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spring security it is indeed possible to register multiple authentication mechanisms.

**BUT** you cannot register a specific authentication provider to a specific route.
The spring securty docs say:

> `ProviderManager` is the most commonly used implementation of `AuthenticationManager`. `ProviderManager` delegates to a `List` of `AuthenticationProviders`. Each `AuthenticationProvider` has an opportunity to indicate that authentication should be successful, fail, or indicate it cannot make a decision and allow a downstream `AuthenticationProvider` to decide.

So in every request, the registered `AuthenticationProvider`s are checked one after the other until one is successful, or all fail.

To solve your problem, you need to define multiple custom authorities, that you assign your users.
Then you secure your endpoints using these authorities.

E.g. you give every ldap user the authority `LDAP_USER` and every api user the authority `API_USER`. Then you configure your security accordingly:

Register all AuthenticationProviders:

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
```

And configure the endpoints:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
      (...)
      .authorizeRequests()

// security for apiuser
      .antMatchers(“/abcd/**).hasRole(“API_USER”)

// security for ldap users
      .antMatchers(“/ghhgh” + "/**").hasRole("LDAP_USER")
      (...)
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Amir Schenell, thanks for you explanation. I tried the same but I am still able to access the ldap endpoints with apiuser

Comment: can you post your current config into your question, so I can have a lokk at it?

Comment: Hi @Amir Schnell , I missed adding authority to ldap and that fixed it. Thankyou so much